# IInAppBillingService always null

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to set up a simple in app purchase, but for some reason I always get a null pointer when I try to query the available items. I tried using a `Handler` to see if it was an issue with waiting, but that didn't work either, it just prevented the code from ever running.

```
public class AdOnsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private IInAppBillingService mService;
    private ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ad_ons);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
        skuList.add(PRODUCT_ID_MORE_REPTILES);
        final Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
        querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mService != null) {
                    //Query items here
                } else {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
                }
            }
        }, 10);

        buttonBuy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBuy);
        buttonBuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), PRODUCT_ID_MORE_REPTILES, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                    startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), 0, 0, 0);
                } catch (RemoteException|IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1001) {
            int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
            String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
            String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                    String sku = json.getString("productId");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Congratulations on your purchase!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mService != null) {
            unbindService(mServiceConn);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A stack trace to show exactly the code which causes the NPE would be handy. But I'm going to assume that what you mean is that `mService` is always null in your `onCreate` call.

You are essentially doing bad program design. Getting available In-app products is a network call. And you shouldn't do an Aysnchronous network call in your `onCreate` method.

Instead, populate a space for the IAPs to go. Then when you get onServiceConnected(), have that trigger a `listProducts()` call. Then when `queryProducts()` gets a result fill the ListView or whatever you created. Otherwise you have a terrible experience for a user who is always offline.